# Qooxdoo table widget: writing edited changes into the remote model

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm using a Qooxdoo table widget attached to a remote model.

Reading remote data into the table worked like charm, but since the table has some editable column, the problem is: how do I instruct the model to write those changed data to the server?

The model is defined by the book, overriding the `_loadRowData` and `_loadRowCount` methods, attached to the related `*Completed` handlers, just like it is described into [this page](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/0.8/remote_table_model).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, the Remote model doesn't provide a way to communicate changes back to the server. Instead, you can listen for the table's "dataEdited" event. Just how you send the changes to the server of course depends on the type of backend you're using.

Comment: Qooxdoo table model need a lot of improvement to be useful at all. The remote model do not even support addRow ..